# No such command 'sip reload' when using asterisk 18

Tags: command-line, networking, asterisk

Every time I restart asterisk my all soft phones are not connecting.

When I am checking my peers with `sip show peers` or `sip reload` command then I am getting errors:-

```
No such command 'sip show peers'
```

or.

```
No such command 'sip reload'
```

I found the temporary solution but when I restart my asterisk I again encounter the same issue

Temporary solution is to run these commands:

```
root@xxxxxxx:~# cd /usr/lib/asterisk/modules
root@xxxxxxx:/usr/lib/asterisk/modules# asterisk -rx "module load chan_sip.so"
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
root@xxxxxxx:/usr/lib/asterisk/modules#
```

**or**

While inside asterisk CLI:

```
module load chan_sip.so
```

In both cases it is working only on a temporary basis because every time I restart asterisk then I have to do it all over again. Has anyone got a permanent solution please? I am stuck.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 2):

In Asterisk 18 the module chan_sip.so is set to noload in the modules.conf file.

If you want to autoload the module just comment the line by adding ";" in front of `noload = chan_sip.so`

[/etc/asterisk/modules.conf]

```
;
; Do not load chan_sip by default, it may conflict with res_pjsip.
;noload = chan_sip.so
;
```